# config parser: Choosing name and value delimiter

Tags: python, configparser

Let's say I have one test.ini file with the following lines:

```
[A]
name1 [0,1]=0
name2 a:b:c / A:B:C [0,1]=1
```

When I parse it like this:

```
A = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
with codecs.open('test.ini', 'r') as f:
    A.optionxform = str
    A.readfp(f)

for section_name in A.sections():
    print 'Section:', section_name
    print 'Options:', A.options(section_name)
    for name, value in A.items(section_name):
        print 'name-value pair:'
        print '%s' % (name)
        print '%s' % (value)
```

I get the following output:

```
Section: A
Options: ['name1 [0,1]', 'name2 a']
name-value pair:
name1 [0,1]
0
name-value pair:
name2 a
b:c / A:B:C [0,1]=1
```

But that is not what I want, 
I want it to be like this:

```
Section: A
Options: ['name1 [0,1]', 'name2 a:b:c / A:B:C [0,1]']
name-value pair:
name1 [0,1]
0
name-value pair:
name2 a:b:c / A:B:C [0,1]
1
```

Is there a way to somehow choose the delimiter 
between name and value so that it only can be `=` sign?

And if there are more than just one `=` in a line, 
that the delimiter be the last one?

Comment: Okay, I found out that, since I'm using Python 2.7, I need to update ConfigParser module to the newer one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser. Now there should be an option for customizing key(name) and value delimiter...

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by skipping to Python 3.3 and: `A = configparser.ConfigParser(delimiters=('='))`