# Is it possible to set colon(':') as the delimiter in a config file using python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I am using Python 2.7.14 and I am trying to set a line in a config file with colon as a delimiter (for example- option : value) with ConfigParser. What I did is this:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(myPath, 'settings.cfg'))
config.add_section("new_section")
config.set('new_section', "option", "value")
with open(os.path.join(myPath, 'new_settings.cfg'), 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

The result is this:

```
[new_section]
option = value
```

What I need it to be is `option: value`

And also all the existing delimiters in the original `settings.cfg` file change to `=` in `new_settings.cfg` file. It seems as there should be a simple solution for it but I just cant to find it anywhere, and upgrading to python 3.x is not an option right now.

Comment: You might upgrade to python 3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328509/python-config-parser-choosing-name-and-value-delimiter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [config parser: Choosing name and value delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328509/config-parser-choosing-name-and-value-delimiter)